# Please help identify what this box is

Tags: identification

What is this? What’s it used for? It appeared for 10 days and was then removed. I checked with our city and the power company and internet/phone companies and no one knows what it was.

[image]

Comment: What country are you in?

Comment: It's a weatherproof container like a Pelican case. Anything could be inside but I'd guess it is being used to do some kind of surveying activity e.g. cellular network monitoring. If the pole has an identification tag the box may be periodically moved to others in the area to build up some kind of mapping.

Comment: Internally there is a camera that photographs anyone getting near to it. The images are then processed in a lab to ascertain who are the most likely to be criminal-minded in your area. It's a social-science experiment used to uncover likely suspects for car thefts and home break-ins. You might receive a visit soon so, please stay calm and hide anything that you might have recently acquired that is not legitimate.

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to the forum! The answer is a 4-step process. I'll do the first three, you do the last if you want.

1. Entering your handle "IAMAW 1763" in Google indicates it's a Union in Dartmouth, Nova Scotia. So maybe that's where this box is.
2. The box has "HTC" labeling. While there is a huge Chinese smartphone manufacturer called "HTC", I didn't think that was the answer. So I googled HTC *and* Dartmouth, Nova Scotia.
3. There are several matches, but I rejected the Halifax Triathlon Club and further down the list found HiTech Communications (HTC) ([website here](http://www.hitechcomm.ca/)). They do all kinds of communications work (asset tracking, remote internet, cell phone boosters to name a few) and I'll bet it was their device.
4. If you are still curious, ring'em up.

Comment: This site isn't a forum.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are this box is for taking anonymous radar traffic density and speed measurements. In my area, exactly those boxes are often put up for a few days on roads where the municipality wants to know if it's useful to have speedbumps or a permanent speed trap.